# Can I run (XAMPP) MySQl inside my DropBox folder?

Tags: mysql, xampp, dropbox

Lots of conflicting reports out there when I google; can anyone help?

Basically I want to have the same databases available at work & home PCs, for development porpoises only.

I will only ever be physically at one PC (with a 45 minute trip between) and only then will there be database access. The MySql service will be running on both, but only one will be write/reading the database. Both run Windows 7

I don't need to bother with symlinks, junctions, etc as I have enough space in my DropBox to install all of Xampp there.

Can I do that without corruption?

Comment: Can't you just setup some port forwarding and firewall rules to make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use something similar as part of my remote development testing, I have never tried to run a large set of data from this or a production database. Haha, but for testing queries and setting up a couple rows, etc... I use something very similar with little to no problems.

Comment: Did anybody have success with this??

Comment: I apolgize, but I never got round to it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can run the portable xampp and mysql from your Dropbox just go to www.portableapps.com to get the xampp and also download the portable launcher from the link on the page.

Comment: This should be comment i think

Answer (score 1):

Let XAMPP server run on your computers, and the data folder saved on your cloud (DropBox, SkyDrive, etc).

You should install XAMPP portable on your root folder (c:) that is the same on all computer you use, then you can move XAMPP data folder (xampp Apache htdocs) and MySQL data (xampp Mysql/data) folder to Dropbox.

Do not use XAMPP installer, but use the portable one.

Configure the folder settings on both Apache and MySQL config file:

- C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf
- C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-ssl.conf
- C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf
- C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini
  Do the same with other server that you use (PostgreSQL, etc).

Make sure that you:

1. Always turn off XAMPP server after using on each PC.
2. Always sync Dropbox before changing PC, that is before logging on and after logging off on different computer.
3. Mind host / local domain variable on each computer.

Its probably better to use same username for all computer you want to use to run the data folder.

Other method is using PortableAppas.com, that is running the apps directly from USB.